# What is the significance of string data member?

Tags: c++, string

[String data](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/data/)

What I am particularly confused about is this statement

"Its contents are guaranteed to remain unchanged only until the next call to a non-constant member function of the string object."

Can someone clarify what does this mean? When to use this and when to avoid using this?

Answer (score 5):

They mean that you could store the pointer and use it later. If some non-const method is called between two accesses the contents of the buffer your stored pointer is set to may change and your will face unexpected behaviour.

Answer (score 4):

```
const char* data() const;
```

This is saying that the `const char *` returned by calling `str.data()` will not change unless someone modifies the string that it came from.  Once someone calls a non-constant member function, the returned pointer could be invalid, or could point to different data from what it pointed to immediately after the `str.data()` function returned.

It means you can pass the returned data to C functions, for example.  It means you should not do something like:

```
const char *old = str.data();
size_t      len = str.length();
...call a function that modifies str...
// cout << old << endl;
// Since old is not guaranteed to be null terminated (thanks MSalter),
// do something else with the old data instead of writing to cout.
// Inventiveness not at a high this morning; this isn't a particularly
// good example of what to do - a sort of string copy.
char buffer[256];
memcpy(buffer, old, MIN(sizeof(buffer)-1, len));
buffer[len] = '\0';
```

By the time the <strike>I/O</strike> memory copying is done, `old` may not be valid any more, and `len` may also be incorrect.

Comment: Addition:
Usually operations on a string cause changes of c-string that is wrapped inside string. As operations like append require reallocation of c-string, it's previous memory location is freed and not used anymore.

Comment: "Usually" being the important word, because there are a number of implementations of std::string that don't wrap a C string (the singlemost common exception is not having a \0 in the wrapped char[])

Comment: Oh, the example is wrong BTW: cout requires a null-terminated string, and data() in general isn't.

Comment: @MSalters: so you are saying - if the member function had been `c_str` instead of `data`, then the result would be guaranteed null terminated, but given that it is `data`, the result is not guaranteed to be null terminated? ...from the URL in the Q: "_Notice that no terminating null character is appended (see member c_str for such a functionality)_"; OK.  My bad.  I'm not sure what you can do safely with the result from `data`; you need to know the length, somehow; presumably string::length() gives the right answer.  Thanks for the heads up - I missed that detail.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes, you need to have access to the string formatted as an array of characters - usually because you need to pass the string to some function which expects the string like this (for example `strcmp`). You can do this by using the `data` or `c_str` members, but you have to respect the rules for calling the function which are spelled out plainly in the link you provided:

> The returned array points to an
>   internal location which should not be
>   modified directly in the program. Its
>   contents are guaranteed to remain
>   unchanged only until the next call to
>   a non-constant member function of the
>   string object.

You cannot modify the array of characters - the string object assumes that you do not, and if you do this will lead to undefined behaviour.